# Error using choroplethr package

Tags: r, choroplethr

I am attempting to use the "choroplethr" package in R, but always get the following error:

Error: Don't know how to add self$ggplot_polygon to a plot

I am using the df_pop_county dataframe from the package.

```
library(choroplethr)
data(df_pop_county)
county_choropleth(df_pop_county)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: when I run your code I have a map of the US in blue shade

Comment: Suspicious of a version mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you have ggplot2 version 2.0.0 installed as well as a version of choroplethr that is less than 3.3.1.

ggplot version 2.0.0 was released on Friday. This was a major update, and choroplethr (as well as, I suspect, several other packages), needed to be updated to be compatible with the new version.

I submitted an udpated version of choroplethr to CRAN last night and it was accepted this morning. You can get it by typing the following from an R console:

```
update.packages()
```

Although it often takes a few days for CRAN to build the binaries and have the new binaries get to all the CRAN mirrors. In the interim, you can get the updated version of choroplethr from github directly. [Here](https://github.com/arilamstein/choroplethr#installation) are the instructions.